# Report Builder result row limit to continue in second column before continuing on next page

Tags: sql-server, resultset, reportbuilder3.0

I have a 3 columned table requested report that has about 200 results pending the parameter limits selected(based on date range). I'd like to limit the rows per page to 30 and have the table/column continue in a second page column to the right before moving to the next page resulting in 3 or 4 pages printed instead of having everything in one table/column with 7 or more pages printed.

[Result Example]

[image]

```
(row 1)1Aa1  3Aa3   5Aa5 
(row 2)2Aa2  4Aa4   5Aa5
--new page--
(row 1)6Aa6  8Aa8   9Aa9
```

[Result Example]
[image]

```
(row 1)1Bb1  3Bb3
(row 2)2Bb2  4Bb4
--new page--
(row1)5Bb5  7Bb7
```

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 with a shared SQL database. Policy for my department includes restriction for creating temporary tables or stored procedures.

```
--create an additional column with expression-- 
    =RowNumber(Nothing)
--1st table
    =IIF(RowNumber("DSRoster") = CountRows("DSRoster") AND RowNumber("DSRoster") mod 2 = 0, false, true)
--2nd table
    =IIF(RowNumber("DSRoster") = CountRows("DSRoster") AND RowNumber("DSRoster") mod 2 = 1, false, true)

--adding columns to the page properties with and without the above code--

--add in SQL query to SELECT--  ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY location_5) AS RowNumber
--add in SQL query after conditions-- ORDER BY location_5
--add to both tables--
    =CStr(CInt(Fields!RowNumber.Value) mod 2)
```

Comment: If you can't modify the data in the dataset query or even use temp tables then the next best thing would be to add calculated fields to your dataset. Go to the dataset properties and add them. I'm not at a PC right now so I can't  check the steps but you can add RowNumber and ColumnNumber fields to the dataset then use a matrix to display the output. Have a look at this answer to give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70119042/ssrs-show-table-list-in-sequence/70123659#70123659